# How to fix an hibernate criteria datepart error?

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain with a calculated field.

> durationInMinutes formula: 'datepart(minute, Duration) + datepart(hour, Duration) * 60'

and use it in a createCriteria

> property('durationInMinutes')

but this generates an error in the logfile

> java.sql.SQLException: 'this_.minute' is not a recognized datepart option.

Please help.
I use MySQL.

Found this working solution:

```
projections {
    sqlProjection '(datepart(minute, Duration) + datepart(hour, Duration) * 60) as TimeInMinutes', 'TimeInMinutes', INTEGER
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the MySQL database, but I think it is a hibernate releated question?